# XFCE Battery indicator and resolution

Tags: xfce

I recently started using Linux Mint with XFCE. I have FHD screen resolution, but everything looks really small to me. Is there any way to make things bigger -- I mean panels in xfce, etc, besides changing the resolution? Are there any sites where I can find plugins to add to my panels in XFCE (battery indicator and maybe some cpu/ram/swap monitor)? The battery indicator in XFCE is so small that I can't see anything.